# Run a cmd command in Java that asks for another input

Tags: java, cmd, outputstream, processbuilder, mosquitto

I should run a command using Java.

The command is:
`mosquitto_ctrl -u admin -P admin dynsec createClient User`

After running the command, it asks me for an input twice like this:

> Enter new password for User. Press return for no password (user will be unable to login).

> New password for User:

and then:

> Reenter password for User:

How could I do as the program gives the input to the cmd automatically?

I tried to write this function but it doesn't work:

```
public static void createMosquittoUser(String username, String password) throws IOException {
    
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
            "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"C:\\mosquitto\" && mosquitto_ctrl -u admin -P admin dynsec createClient " + username);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
        os.write(password.getBytes());
        os.write(password.getBytes());
        os.close();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) { break; }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    
}
```

How could I fix it so it does all the command automatically?

Comment: You are already writing to the output stream which is the right approach. 2 potential problems: 1) i wonder whether it's expecting a newline or some other character after the password is entered, otherwise how does it know the password is finished? 2) i wonder if it's possible to write to the output stream prematurely. Maybe you need to wait until the prompt appears, by monitoring the input stream.

Comment: For the end of the password when I run it from terminal it requires the "enter" button to be pushed, but I don't know how to do it using Java. I don't even know how could I let it wait to avoid to write to the output stream prematurely

Comment: You are already looping over the input. So something like `if (line.contains("password")) os.write(password.getBytes())`

Comment: It tried but unfortunately it doesn't work